# How to create such onclick effect in CSS?

Tags: css, button, onclick

Does anyone know how is it possible to create such an onclick effect as on picture? (I mean the colorful highlight of cursor only at the place of click)

[image]

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

First you create an empty div (`<div id="mouseclickhighlight"> <div>` for example) and add CSS to make it look like that yellow circle, or w/e other style you like.

Something along the lines of:

```
#mouseclickhighlight {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Check out how it looks, tune it to your wishes, and then also add `display: none;` in there.

After that you'll only have to add a tiny bit of javascript, to listen for mouseclick/mousedown events, and when they happen you:

1. Set `#mouseclickhighlight`s position to the events's position (using `top`&`left`)
2. Set `display: block` to make it visible,
3. Start a 1 second timer which hides it again

---

That is the rough idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and help! 
Have a wonderful day ahead :)